# How do I write code to determine whether the EOL character in a CSV file is `\r` or `\n` without looking at the file contents?

Tags: python, eol, end-of-line

I'm using Python in Jupyter Notebooks to work with a CSV file. I'm writing the same code in two different versions of Jupyter Notebook--one that's running directly on my computer and another that's running off a kind of emulator within an online lesson from Dataquest. When I open the CSV file and read it into a string on my computer's Jupyter Notebook, the EOL character is `\r` but when I do the same on Dataquest's emulator, the EOL character is `\n`. I have two questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I write a Python code that tests for the EOL character without opening the file to find out visually?

This code in in a Jupyter notebook on my own Mac.

```
f = open('US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv', 'r')
data_MyComp = f.read()
data_MyComp
```

This code is on Dataquest's Jupyter notebook browser emulator.

```
f = open('US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv', 'r')
data_dataquest = f.read()
data_dataquest
```

This is a few lines of output from my computer when I run `data_MyComp` (note the EOL character is `\r`).

```
'year,month,date_of_month,day_of_week,births\r1994,1,1,6,8096\r1994,1,2,7,7772\r1994,1,3,1,10142\r1994,1,4,2,11248\r1994,1,5,3,11053\r1994,1,6,4,11406\r1994,1,7,5,11251\r1994,1,8,6,8653\r1994,1,9,7,7910\r1994,1,10,1,10498\r1994,1,11,2,11706\r
```

This is a few lines of output from the Dataquest emulator when I run `data_dataquest` (note the EOL character is `\n`).

```
'year,month,date_of_month,day_of_week,births\n1994,1,1,6,8096\n1994,1,2,7,7772\n1994,1,3,1,10142\n1994,1,4,2,11248\n1994,1,5,3,11053\n1994,1,6,4,11406\n
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open  the `newline` flag handles that for you, or am I missing something?

Comment: I suppose "opening the file" really means "manual inspection" here. In order to process the contents of a file you *have* to `open()` it.

Comment: Is your own computer by any chance running Windows? How exactly are you making the file available to Jupyter?

Comment: If you just want to read the CSV file, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the standard library. It should properly handle the line endings on its own.

Comment: @tripleee 
Yes, I mean "manual inspection". Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @tripleee I edited the question a bit further. Hopefully, it's clearer.

Comment: @tripleee 

I'm on a Mac running OSX not a Windows machine. 
The file is available here:
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv

I saved it as a CSV to my machine and then opened it using the code shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Without any indication of how you downloaded or otherwise made the file available to Python and Jupyter, we can't really tell why this is happening.  Line endings are platform-specific but Python 3 should generally neutralize differences between platforms unless you specifically request opening a file as "binary".

You can discover the line-ending conventions by simply opening the file and reading enough of it.  What's "enough" depends on the file type.  Perhaps something like this in your case:

```
with open('US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv', 'rb') as peek:
    buf = peek.read(1024)
    if b'\r\n' in peek:
        print("DOS CR/LF line terminator")
    elif b'\r' in peek:
        print("Plain CR seen (legacy Mac or CP/M file)?")
    elif b'\n' in peek:
        print("Plain LF seen (standard Unix text file)")
```

This doesn't attempt to do any statistical analysis, but might work well enough for your limited case.  The file will be closed again after the end of the `with` block so you can then just open it a second time with the parameters you actually need.